# bootstrap 5 carousel play pause button function

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, carousel, bootstrap-5

Using jQuery, how do create play/pause on same button on clicking in bootstrap 5 carousel

**HTML **

```
<div id="customSlider" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval="2500">
    <div class="container ">
        <div class="carousel-indicators customSlider-indi">
            <a data-bs-target="#customSlider" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Lorem 1">
                <span class="banner-label">Lorem 1</span></a>
            <a data-bs-target="#customSlider" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Lorem 2">
                <span class="banner-label">Lorem 2</span>
            </a>
            <a data-bs-target="#customSlider" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Lorem 3">
                <span class="banner-label">Lorem 3</span>
            </a>
            <a data-bs-target="#customSlider" data-bs-slide-to="3" aria-label="Lorem 3">
                <span class="banner-label">Lorem 4</span>
            </a>
            <a id="playBtn" data-cplay="true" class="play-btn play">
                <span class="icon-pause">&nbsp;</span>
                <span class="playPauseText">Pause</span>
            </a>
            <!--         <a class="btn  play">Play</a>
          <a class="btn stop">Stop</a> -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1440x500/210471?text=image_1" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="custom-cap">
                    <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum maxime aut optio? Est eum laudantium qui aliquam tenetur mollitia, officiis enim laboriosam amet sapiente illum autem maxime molestias, sed ullam!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1440x500/210471?text=image_2" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            <div class="container">

                <div class="custom-cap">
                    <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum maxime aut optio? Est eum laudantium qui aliquam tenetur mollitia, officiis enim laboriosam amet sapiente illum autem maxime molestias, sed ullam!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1440x500/210471?text=image_3" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="custom-cap">
                    <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum maxime aut optio? Est eum laudantium qui aliquam tenetur mollitia, officiis enim laboriosam amet sapiente illum autem maxime molestias, sed ullam!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1440x500/210471?text=image_4" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="custom-cap">
                    <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum maxime aut optio? Est eum laudantium qui aliquam tenetur mollitia, officiis enim laboriosam amet sapiente illum autem maxime molestias, sed ullam!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**style**

```
.play-btn {
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: 0 0;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.play-btn .icon-pause {
    width: 8px;
    height: 12px;
    border-left: 2px solid #fff;
    border-right: 2px solid #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 14px;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}


.play-btn .playPauseText {
    left: 30px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-weight: var(--ds-font-500);
    font-size: var(--ds-font-16);
    line-height: 1.4;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}

.play-btn:is(:hover, :focus) {
    width: 85px;
}

.play-btn:is(:hover, :focus) .playPauseText {
    opacity: 1;
}

.banner-label {
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -5px;
    padding: 0px 3px;
}

.customSlider-indi {
    background: transparent;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 10px;
    bottom: 20px;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

.customSlider-indi [data-bs-target] {
    flex: none;
    font-size: var(--ds-font-16);
    text-indent: 0;
    width: auto;
    background: transparent;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    height: 36px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 0px !important;
    align-items: center;
}

.customSlider-indi [data-bs-target]:is(:hover, :focus) {
    color: #fff;
}

.customSlider-indi [data-bs-target]::after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: opacity .6s ease
}

.custom-cap {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    color: #fff;
}

.custom-cap h5 {
    font-family: var(--ds-font-300);
    font-size: 56px;
    color: var(--ds-white);
}

.custom-cap p {
    font-size: var(--ds-font-22);
    font-family: var(--ds-font-300);
    color: var(--ds-white);
}
```

**script**

```
var myCarousel = document.querySelector('#customSlider');
    var carousel = new bootstrap.Carousel(myCarousel);

    $('#playBtn').click(function () {
        if ($(this).data('cplay') == "true") {
            $(this).data('cplay', 'false');
            $(this).removeClass("play");
            $(this).addClass("stop");
            $(this).find(".playPauseText").text("Pause");

            document.querySelector('.stop').addEventListener('click', function () {
                e.preventDefault();
                carousel.pause();
            });
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass("play");
            $(this).data('cplay', 'true');
            $(this).removeClass("stop");
            $(this).find(".playPauseText").text("Play");

            document.querySelector('.play').addEventListener('click', function () {
                e.preventDefault();
                carousel.cycle();
            });
        }
    });
```

I would like to have the carousel play on load, and have a pause/play button to control it.

I have tried, and for some reason I cannot seem to get the button to pause on "pause" click, and resume play when "play" clicked.

please help me solve using jQuery or JS

Answer (score -1):

Here is a revised version of your script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var myCarousel = $('#customSlider');
    var carousel = new bootstrap.Carousel(myCarousel[0], {
        interval: 2500,
        ride: 'carousel'
    });

    // Start the carousel on load
    carousel.cycle();

    $('#playBtn').click(function () {
        var isPlaying = $(this).data('cplay');

        if (isPlaying) {
            // If the carousel is playing, pause it
            carousel.pause();
            $(this).data('cplay', false);
            $(this).removeClass("play").addClass("stop");
            $(this).find(".playPauseText").text("Play");
        } else {
            // If the carousel is paused, start it
            carousel.cycle();
            $(this).data('cplay', true);
            $(this).removeClass("stop").addClass("play");
            $(this).find(".playPauseText").text("Pause");
        }
    });
});
```